# Gimp Transparency Not Working

Tags: transparency, gimp

So I am trying to remove a certain color: e95353 from an image. It is the background of the image. However, the main clip which I want to keep has very similar colors, here it is:
[image]

When I try to remove e95353 from the image, here is what happens:

[image]

As you see, parts of the iamge are removed why should not be removed. How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: How is this programming related?

Comment: @Midas its not, I didn't tag this in programming.

Comment: There is no such tag, because this site *is* solely for programming! :)

Comment: @Midas ah, ok, I am looking at the gimp questions and I see that they are about scripts, sorry about that!

Comment: try at graphicdesign.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Transparency (I assume *Color-to-apha*) works... The "contract" is that after removal of a given color, you can put the resulting image over a background filled with that removed color and you will get back the original image.

The trouble is that this operation is ambiguous, a light gray can be obtained as a rather transparent black over white, or as a fully opaque light gray, or as slightly transparent dark gray. Or light red over dark red as a semi-transparent white or as a completely opaque light red, if you take my drift. So you have an infinity of solutions... and Gimp takes the solution that is the most transparent.

So, if you don't want some element of your picture to be included in the Color-To-Alpha, just use a selection to exclude them (but this selection should include the border pixels if you want smooth lines in the result).